# AWS S3 returning differing "Content-Range" compared to "Range" request header specification

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, get

We send the "Range" Header with our HTTP Get Requests to S3 for resuming failed downloads of our ~3GB application that we host there. A strange behavior has occurred. While at "lower" completion percentages (0-50%), the returned Content-Range Header from the server exactly matches up with what we requested. However, at a certain, yet undetermined point, the returned Content-Range is differing from our requests. We always request from XYZ bytes to end. I yet had no time to debug whether there is a well defined "boarder" after which this behavior occurs, I can only assure that it always happens after 75%, a mark at which I tested a dozen times already, and doesn't happen at anything lower than 50%.

My question is whether this is expectable behavior as I cannot see any documentation about this. If it is, is there any resources to get familiar with this behavior or even a way to prevent it? For example, we requested the range to start at 2566960807 bytes, S3 responded with Content-Range: bytes 1499653561-3227660049. This is quite a large chunk that would needed to be re-downloaded. The amount of successful, preceding partial content requests seems to be of no relevancy, e.g. the same behavior is to be experienced when multiple or none "Range" requests (which had returned the "correct" byte range) have been made on the same object beforehand.

If this information is of any relevancy, between the failure of the initial download (killed internet connection) until the attempted ranged continuation only are a couple seconds. (~10-20 seconds max)

Comment: Ask this on the AWS forums.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is interested in the solution, the issue was surprisingly stupid. The library we used for the downloaded was using .Net 3.5, where HttWebRequest.AddRange only supported int. Passing in a long parameter lead to a cast error when the int range was exceeded. Have to say, really questionable implementation by Avira (we use their FileDownloader), casting a long to int unchecked.